# removeView(mView) throws a illegalArgumentException

Tags: android, view, overlay, illegalargumentexception

I define a custom float view component according to the tutorial online, but the problem is everytime i call removeView(), there is a exception, every other part works fine, following is the onclick listener.

```
  followButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          ImageView focusView = new ImageView(getActivity());
          focusView.setImageResource(R.drawable.follow_me);
          WindowManager.LayoutParams focusParam = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
          focusParam.type=2002;
          focusParam.format=1;
          focusParam.flags=40;  //default（32）+ FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE（8）
          focusParam.width=30;
          focusParam.height=30;
          focusParam.x=0;focusParam.y=0;
          focusParam.setTitle("Load Average");
          WindowManager wm1 = (WindowManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);              
            followModeOn=!followModeOn;
            if (followModeOn) {
                  wm1.addView(focusView, focusParam);
            }
            else {
                wm1.removeView(focusView);
            }
        }
    });
```

Here is the error report:

```
01-23 00:06:39.163: E/AndroidRuntime(31651): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=android.widget.ImageView{46586dc0 V.ED.... ......I. 0,0-0,0} not attached to window manager
01-23 00:06:39.163: E/AndroidRuntime(31651):    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:370)
01-23 00:06:39.163: E/AndroidRuntime(31651):    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:299)
01-23 00:06:39.163: E/AndroidRuntime(31651):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:79)
01-23 00:06:39.163: E/AndroidRuntime(31651):    at study.runtracker.map.OSMFragment$4.onClick(OSMFragment.java:180)
01-23 00:06:39.163: E/AndroidRuntime(31651):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
01-23 00:06:39.163: E/AndroidRuntime(31651):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
01-23 00:06:39.163: E/AndroidRuntime(31651):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
01-23 00:06:39.163: E/AndroidRuntime(31651):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-23 00:06:39.163: E/AndroidRuntime(31651):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-23 00:06:39.163: E/AndroidRuntime(31651):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
01-23 00:06:39.163: E/AndroidRuntime(31651):    at 

java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

01-23 00:06:39.163: E/AndroidRuntime(31651):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-23 00:06:39.163: E/AndroidRuntime(31651):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
01-23 00:06:39.163: E/AndroidRuntime(31651):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
01-23 00:06:39.163: E/AndroidRuntime(31651):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

this cant work. you are creating a new ImageView everytime you receive a click, you need to keep a reference on the one that is created in the first place.

As you are recreating it everytime, the new view cant be removed from the view because it has never been added to the "parent" view.

Answer (score 0):

As the Log cat says, `focusView` has not been attached to WindowManager. You're creating a brand new ImageView, and then trying to remove it before attaching it.

I would try keeping a reference to the focusView so you can remove it later.

```
View mFocusView = null;

followButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Create the focus view, if not already done
        if (mFocusView == null)
            mFocusView = new ImageView(getActivity());

        mFocusView.setImageResource(R.drawable.follow_me);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams focusParam = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        focusParam.type=2002;
        focusParam.format=1;
        focusParam.flags=40;  //default（32）+ FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE（8）
        focusParam.width=30;
        focusParam.height=30;
        focusParam.x=0;focusParam.y=0;
        focusParam.setTitle("Load Average");
        WindowManager wm1 = (WindowManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

        followModeOn=!followModeOn;
        // This will work as long as followModeOn is false here, the first pass through.
        if (followModeOn) {
            wm1.addView(mFocusView, focusParam);
        }
        else {
            wm1.removeView(mFocusView);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestions, now I move one constructor out of onclick and problem solved.

```
      ImageView focusView = new ImageView(getActivity());
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {             
          focusView.setImageResource(R.drawable.follow_me);
```